# Resizable child element with absolute position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**Problem:** when I'm resizing parent image, I also want children div resize, but with correct ratio and position. So no matter how I resize image, children div will always cover this part of the image, which is covering at the begining.

**Html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <img src=" http://s3.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_prod_assets/assets/images/original/0002/8857/28857v1.gif" alt="" width="400px" height="300px" id="res">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 286px;
    height: 133px;
    left: 107px;
    top: 38px;    background: yellow;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

**Js:**

```
$( "#res" ).resizable({ alsoResize: ".cover"});
```

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MKtWq/1/

Any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly help : http://jsfiddle.net/MKtWq/79/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="cover"><img src="http://s0.uploads.im/aLNwR.png" width=100% height=100%/></div>

<img src=" http://s3.amazonaws.com/crunchbase_prod_assets/assets/images/original/0002/8857/28857v1.gif" alt="" width="400" height="300" id="res">
```

JS:

```
$( ".cover" ).resizable({ alsoResize: "#res"});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    left:0%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your trying, but this is not solving my problem. I want to resize div, not image on top of image.